# How do I attach multiple files to an email using Perl?

Tags: perl, email, perl-module, attachment, mailx

I find it hard to believe that this question doesn't exist on SO, but I couldn't find an instance or one similar for Perl....

Anyway, what Perl module should I use to attach multiple files to an email?

Currently, I'm using this code to send an email with a single attachment, but I couldn't figure out how to modify it to handle multiple attachments:

```
my $mail_fh = \*MAIL;
open $mail_fh, "|uuencode $attachment $attachment |mailx -m -s \"$subject\" -r $sender $recipient";
print $mail_fh $message;
close($mail_fh);
```

Can this code block be modified to handle multiple attachments?  Or do I have to use a special module to pull this off?  If so, what is the module and how would I script it out?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: There are a myriad Mail modules on CPAN - choose one and use it.  And don't use uuencode; it was replaced by Base-64 encoding for a lot of good reasons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up going with an example using `MIME::Lite` found [here](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/12995-perl-emailing-multiple-files-attachment.html)

```
use MIME::Lite;
use Getopt::Std;

my $SMTP_SERVER = 'smtp.server.com';             #change
my $DEFAULT_SENDER = 'default@sender.com';       #change
my $DEFAULT_RECIPIENT = 'default@recipient.com'; #change

MIME::Lite->send('smtp', $SMTP_SERVER, Timeout=>60);

my (%o, $msg);

# process options

getopts('hf:t:s:', \%o);

$o{f} ||= $DEFAULT_SENDER;
$o{t} ||= $DEFAULT_RECIPIENT;
$o{s} ||= 'Files';

if ($o{h} or !@ARGV) {
    die "usage:\n\t$0 [-h] [-f from] [-t to] [-s subject] files ...\n";
}

# construct and send email

$msg = new MIME::Lite(
    From => $o{f},
    To   => $o{t},
    Subject => $o{s},
    Data => "Data",
    Type => "multipart/mixed",
);

while (@ARGV) {
  $msg->attach('Type' => 'application/octet-stream',
               'Encoding' => 'base64',
               'Path' => shift @ARGV);
}

$msg->send(  );
```

example usage:

```
./notify_mime.pl -f cheese -t queso -s subject /home/id/cheeseconqueso/some_dir/example1.xls /home/id/cheeseconqueso/some_other_dir/*.xls
```

Answer (score 2):

See `attach_file` in [Email::Stuff](http://p3rl.org/Email%3a%3aStuff), or [Email::MIME](http://p3rl.org/Email%3a%3aMIME#SYNOPSIS) if you need more control.

Answer (score 1):

Despite mixed ratings, I've found [Mail::Sender](http://search.cpan.org/~jenda/Mail-Sender/) (and it's pal [Mail::Sender::Easy](http://search.cpan.org/~dmuey/Mail-Sender-Easy/)) darn good and straightforward to use, and looks like it can handle multiple attachments.

I found the interface to be extremely annoying in [Mail::Internet](http://search.cpan.org/~markov/MailTools-2.07/lib/Mail/Internet.pod).

Anything should be better than what you have above, though. :-)